# SQL Server query for all columns with group by and having

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sybase

I'm wondering is there a way to query all columns with group by and having in SQL Server? For example, I have 6 columns, a, b,…,f, and this is something I want to get:

```
Select *
From table
Group by table.b, table.c
Having max(table.d)=table.d
```

This works in sybase, since I'm trying to migrate stuff from sybase to SQL Server, I'm not sure what I can do in new environment. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a window function e.g. `row_number` in SQL Server when you need all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to group by every column when you don't use any aggragate-functions in your select? Just use the following code to get all columns of the table:

```
select * from table
```

Group by only gets used when you have aggragete-functions (e.g. max(), avg(), count(), ...) in your select.

Having limits the aggrageted columns and where the normal columns of the table.

Comment: Hi, because I need to filter out the max d for each group, say there would be some records with same b, c, and I want to get the one with largest d, That why I need group and having clause here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN, MAX, AVG, and COUNT functions with the OVER clause to provide aggregated values for each column` (to imitate the group by clause for each column) and Common table expression CTE to filter out the results (to imitate the having clause) as:

```
;With CTE as
(
SELECT  
         MIN(a) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS MinCol_a  
       , MAX(b) OVER (PARTITION BY b) AS MaxCol_b 
       , AVG(c) OVER (PARTITION BY c) AS AvgCol_c  
       , COUNT(e) OVER (PARTITION BY d) AS Counte_PerCol_d  
FROM Tbl_Test   
)
select MinCol_a,MaxCol_b ,AvgCol_c,Counte_PerCol_d  
from CTE 
Join --here you can join the table Test results with other tables 
where --any filter condition similar to Having clause
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get the rows with maximum `d` for each combination of `b` and `c` then use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where b = t.b and c = t.c and d > t.d 
)
```

or with `rank()` window function:

```
select t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e, t.f
from (
  select *, 
    rank() over (partition by b, c order by d desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using **having** you can get the result which you want. Try below

```
Select table.b, table.c, max(table.d)
From table
Group by table.b, table.c
```